\luastring variant that expands tokens once if they are a cs
luacode's command "\luastringO{m}" expands the first token of m once. I would like to make a variant that goes through all tokens in m, and if a token is a command-sequence, expand it only once.
EDIT:
To further clarify, I want to make a command \luastringA{m} that first expands every token in m once, say call this result n, and then applies a \luastringN{n} around this. Alternatively, an intermediate command sequence can be defined (let's call it \o) (which expands to n, (where noted above that n is m but with each token expanded once) and then apply \luastringO{\o} around it.
EDIT 2: Updated example below. This \luastringA{}will ultimately be used \luadirect{} so that the contents are interpreted in a lua function:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tokcycle}


\xtokcycleenvironment\luastringAenv
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks[1]{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {}
  {\cytoks\expandafter{\expandafter\luastringO\expandafter{\the\cytoks}}}

\def\luastringA#1{\luastringAenv#1\endluastringAenv}


\NewDocumentCommand{\testcommand}{m}{%
  \luastringA{#1}  % this works as requested :)
  % \luadirect{texio.write_nl(\luastringA{#1}..' <<<')} % this does not work :(
  \luadirect{texio.write_nl(\luastring{#1}..' <<<')} % 
 }


\begin{document}

\def\zzz{Hi Mom}

\luastringA{Hmmm. \zzz.}  % this works
\testcommand{Hmmm. \zzz.}

\end{document}



that's quite hard and unlike any normal tex expansion, once you expand the first token, its replacement text is injected into the input buffer ahead of the rest of the argument so if you are expanding the natural thing to expand next is the replacement text of that token, there is no direct way to jump to the end of the replacement and start expanding from there. of course you can in theory parse everything by hand, but what is the use case here? is there a simpler mechanism that can be used that is more in line with normal TeX processing? eg using\expanded to expand the whole thing?

My use is for key-val arguments, I want to write to a file by say title=\@title, author=\@author and I want to expand those cs's only once. I don't want to fully expand \@author because I'll want to replace \and that could be in there. I wonder if I can do this within lua where iterating through the tokens and checking could be easier.

I would look to use \directlua so it all expands (I never find luacode particularly helpful) and arrange to put title=\unexpanded\expandafter{\@title} into the argument  so that full expansion only expands \@title once. (that's basically what expl3 list iterators do for similar reasons)

Perhaps a token cycle is what you are looking for.
UPDATED ANSWER
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\xtokcycleenvironment\foo
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks[1]{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {}
  {\cytoks\expandafter{\expandafter\luastringA\expandafter{\the\cytoks}}}
\let\luastringA\luastringO  % placeholder for my variant
\begin{document}
\def\z{{Hi Mom}}
\def\mycs{it worked \z} 
1. \foo hello \mycs\endfoo

2. \foo it worked \z\endfoo

Detokenization: \detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}
\end{document}


ORIGINAL ANSWER (before clarification)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\begin{document}
\let\luastringA\luastringO  % placeholder for my variant

\def\mycs{it worked} 

\luastringA{\mycs}

\Macrodirective{\addcytoks{\luastringA{#1}}}
\tokencyclexpress hello \mycs\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}


I'm not sure how the OP wants it if \mycs itself contains macros, but perhaps fully expanding the \addcytoks makes more sense, by using the [x] option:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\begin{document}
\let\luastringA\luastringO  % placeholder for my variant

\def\mycs{it worked \today} 

\luastringA{\mycs}

\Macrodirective{\addcytoks[x]{\luastringA{#1}}}
\tokencyclexpress hello \mycs\endtokencyclexpress

Detokenization: \detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}
\end{document}



This could be it! Will do some testing.

To clarify what I'm looking for (will update question soon), is that I want to make a command \luastringA{m} that first expands every token in m once, and then applies a \luastringN{m} around it.

Please see the update. Hopefully this clarifies.

@likethevegetable Please see my updated answer.

I updated my example to include something that more closely resembles my use-case. I'm running into errors when I use what you propose in a \luadirect{}. Any thoughts on the matter?  Thanks!

@likethevegetable I am not a lua person, so please tell me, for your revised example, what result you expect versus what result is presented.

@likethevegetable For example, if I, inside the \testcommand macro, replace the lua call with \luadirect{texio.write_nl("Hmmm. Hi Mom."..' <<<')}, which would presumably give you what you want, I see no change in the output nor log file.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I started a chat. I'm actually running into compilation errors. ! Undefined control sequence. \luastringAenv ...gingroup \long \def \tcafterenv                                                    ##1{\tc@defx \tcendgroup {...  .... ! Undefined control sequence. \addcytoks ->\futurelet \nxttok                                  \addcytoks@A 
